# JQuery ajax call in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can anyone give me the idea for How can I make JQuery ajax call in ASP.NET with an example?

Comment: jquery is client side code and not hardly connected with asp.net. You can see docs and samples here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Make some effort and show what you have tried. Google jquery ajax example. There are a lot of resources available on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2012/07/15/how-to-access-page-methods-from-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Whilst its not technically jQuery AJAX you can grab the ASP.NET AJAX package and use an `UpdatePanel`. Theres a nice tutorial over at the [ASP.NET AJAX Site](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx).

Alternatively you can just grab the jQuery package and use with some  tags but the ViewState can get in the way when you do things like this, I'd suggest using the built in ASP.NET AJAX System for this.

If however your just using it to fetch some JSON/JSONP then you can use the WCF model or the [WebMethod] attribute and fetch them without worrying about the viewstate.

Comment: @AmiramKorach your quite right, I've updated the answer to reflect that.